Do all the remnant vault Icons look the same?
In Mass Effect: Andromeda, do all the remnant vault Icons look the same? How do I know if I’m looking at a vault Icon and not just a remnant point icon on the map? That's my issue right now.
I cleared some points of interest that had the remnant symbol, but I’m not sure if they are vaults or not, or just remnant sites because they turned blue after killing the enemies and looting the chest.

Actually, remnant vault icons and remnant site icons look different on the map. Vault icons, represent major plot locations, appear as larger triangular structures with three points and do not change color upon clearing. However, remnant site icons are smaller, have a diamond with a circle inside, and turn blue after you clear the enemies and loot the area.
